# Market licensing API on Android emulator issues

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, android-lvl

I have an Android app that uses the license checking API. I've set up emulator AVDs with the Google APIs for API levels 8, 9, and 10. My app works fine with the level 8 AVD but fails miserably with the level 9 and 10 AVDs. Here is a typical logcat sequence:

```
02-14 17:43:55.815: INFO/LicenseChecker(448): Binding to licensing service.
02-14 17:43:55.935: WARN/ActivityManager(65): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }: not found
02-14 17:43:55.935: ERROR/LicenseChecker(448): Could not bind to service.
02-14 17:44:00.625: INFO/ActivityManager(65): Displayed com.zigzagworld.tehillim/.Tehillim: +2m1s448ms (total +5m43s546ms)
02-14 17:44:01.085: INFO/ARMAssembler(65): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001002_00000000 [ 87 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x439de6f0:0x439de8a8] in 5603158 ns
02-14 17:44:18.025: INFO/InputReader(65): Device reconfigured: id=0x0, name=qwerty, display size is now 320x480
02-14 17:44:18.025: WARN/InputReader(65):   Touch device did not report support for X or Y axis!
02-14 17:44:19.005: WARN/InputManagerService(65): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40945580
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448): Activity com.zigzagworld.tehillim.Tehillim has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker@4051ba58 that was originally bound here
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.zigzagworld.tehillim.Tehillim has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker@4051ba58 that was originally bound here
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:938)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:833)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:864)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker.checkAccess(LicenseChecker.java:143)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at com.zigzagworld.tehillim.Tehillim.onCreate(Tehillim.java:76)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-14 17:44:20.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(448):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 17:44:20.835: WARN/ActivityManager(65): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40774fd0
```

(I've verified that my test account is set up in all emulators and I've set up the developer console to return a response of LICENSED for the test account.) The error about leaking a connection occurs after I complete the `dontAllow()` processing in my `LicenseCheckerCallback`.

My code is pretty vanilla. I run the following in `onCreate()`:

```
String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
AESObfuscator ob = new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId);
LicenseChecker checker = new LicenseChecker(this,
    new ServerManagedPolicy(this, ob), BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
checker.checkAccess(this);
```

Did something change in the licensing code after API 8? Has anyone else been able to test licensing in anything other than API 8?

Update: The same problem happens with the Market Licensing Sample app that Google supplies.

Comment: Well, evidently it's a known issue, according to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9b1ae385f79af70b/1d61bf8d48e9b6b4?pli=1) on Android Developers forum. :(

Comment: Does someone know solution for this issue?

Comment: Hey Ted! Did you ever find a solution for this issue? I am running into it also.

Comment: @RedCricket - Nope. It's still a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't bind to service usually means you haven't declared that service in your Manifest.

[Read up here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html#impl-lc)

Your secondary error:

```
  Activity com.zigzagworld.tehillim.Tehillim has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker@4051ba58 that was originally bound here
```

Means your service is leaking, do you tear it down when the Activity finished?

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    checker.onDestroy();
    ...
}
```

Ref: [cleanup api](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html#handler-cleanup)

Comment: The manifest is fine. (After all, it works with API level 8.) I'm already calling `checker.onDestroy()` from the activity's `onDestroy` method.